# Jersey 3 with CDI Weld 4 instead of HK2

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, weld, hk2

I have a small JAX-RS (Jersey 3.0.1) API running in a standalone Jetty 11 but want to use Weld 4.0.0 instead of HK2. The Jetty bootstraps the Weld context properly (Jetty module `ci-decorate` was installed as described in the [Weld documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_jetty))

```
WELD-ENV-001212: Jetty CdiDecoratingListener support detected, CDI injection will be available in Listeners, Servlets and Filters.
```

When it comes to call the API endpoint an exception occurs:

```
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 1
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-001304: More than one context active for scope type jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.internalGetContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:672)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.isContextActive(BeanManagerImpl.java:658)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:694)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:717)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiUtil.getBeanReference(CdiUtil.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier$1.getInstance(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier._provide(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.RequestScopedCdiBeanSupplier.get(RequestScopedCdiBeanSupplier.java:46)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.provide(InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.java:53)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:129)
```

My dependencies in the *pom.xml* look as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

For the Weld context there exists an empty *beans.xml* in folder *webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml* declared with `bean-discovery-mode="all"`.
The JAX-RS endpoint class is shown next:

```
import de.test.weld.service.AddressRepository;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("address")
public class AddressApi {

    @Inject
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getAddress() {
        return "{\"street\": \"" + addressRepository.getStreet(0) + "\", \"postcode\":  \"" +
                addressRepository.getPostcode(0) + "\", \"city\": \"" + addressRepository.getCity(0) + "\"}";
    }
}
```

The bean `AddressRepositoryImpl` which I want to inject is annotated with `@jakarta.inject.Singleton`.

I would appreciate any hint so it works with CDI Weld.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the wrong dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

which exists only for non-JEE environments, i.e. Java Standard Edition (SE) or non-webapps.

Then the following dependency was still missing:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Solution refers to: [Jersey Github Issues](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/4628#issuecomment-720619082)